# How to Bind ViewModal to Dropdownlist in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, viewmodel

Suppose that we have a doctor with its weekday schedule. I want to display this weekday schedule and update it in the *view*. My **WeekDay** class looks like this:

```
public class WeekDay
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string DayName { get; set; }
        public string EightTen { get; set; }
        public string TenTwelve { get; set; }
        public string TwelveFourteen { get; set; }
        public string FourteenSixteen { get; set; }
        public int DoctorId { get; set; }
        public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    }
```

And Here is the ViewModel I've created to pass it to the view:

```
public class DoctorWeekDaysViewModel
    {
        public DoctorWeekDaysViewModel()
        {
            WeekDays = new List<WeekDay>();
        }
        public DoctorWeekDaysViewModel(IEnumerable<WeekDay> weekDay = null)
        {
            WeekDays = weekDay ?? new List<WeekDay>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<WeekDay> WeekDays { get; set; }
    }
```

In the controller, the corresponding action will return 6 objects of **WeekDay** Class. In this situation, I've converted it into list and created a *ViewModel* and returned the *ViewModel* to the *view*:

```
public ActionResult EditTimeTable()
        {
            string username = Session["Username"].ToString();
            var doctor = _context.Doctors.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Username.Equals(username));

            var weekdays = _context.WeekDays.Include(a => a.Doctor).Where(a => a.DoctorId.Equals(doctor.Id)).ToList();


            DoctorWeekDaysViewModel viewModel = new DoctorWeekDaysViewModel(weekdays);

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Then In the view I've took it and showed it this way:

```
@model ClinicWebApp.Models.ViewModel.DoctorWeekDaysViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        <div class="calendar-main mb-30">
                            <div class="row"> 
                                @{
                                    var listItems = new List<ListItem> { 
                                        new ListItem { Text = "استراحت", Value = "استراحت" }, 
                                        new ListItem { Text = "ویزیت", Value = "ویزیت" }, 
                                        new ListItem { Text = "نهار", Value = "نهار" },
                                        new ListItem { Text = "صبحانه", Value = "صبحانه" },
                                        new ListItem { Text = "خالی", Value = "خالی" },
                                    };
                                }

                                <table class="mb-0 table table-hover table-dark">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                                            <th scope="col">8 تا 10</th>
                                            <th scope="col">10 تا 12</th>
                                            <th scope="col">12 تا 14</th>
                                            <th scope="col">14 تا 16</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach (var weekday in Model.WeekDays)
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <th scope="row">@weekday.DayName</th>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => weekday.EightTen, new SelectList(listItems), weekday.EightTen, new {@class = "custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2"})
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => weekday.TenTwelve, new SelectList(listItems), weekday.TenTwelve, new {@class = "custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2"})
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => weekday.TwelveFourteen, new SelectList(listItems), weekday.TwelveFourteen, new {@class = "custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2"})
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => weekday.FourteenSixteen, new SelectList(listItems), weekday.FourteenSixteen, new {@class = "custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2"})
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <footer class="bg-white p-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="pull-left">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </footer>
                    }
```

The Output of This View is fine and everything is shown correctly:
[Actual Html Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQAPu.png)

But when I change the dropdownlist values and submit it to the corresponding action, The ViewModel will be null. here is my ActionResult:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditTimeTable(DoctorWeekDaysViewModel viewModel)
        {
            ...
        }
```

I think the problem is my viewModel or dropdownlist that configured incorrectly. please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should custome Name of dropdown to make it correctly.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => weekday.EightTen, new SelectList(listItems), weekday.EightTen, new {@class = "custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2", Name = "WeekDays[0].EightTen"})
```

Note: `Name = WeekDays[0].EightTen`

1. **0**: Index, increase for each loop.
2. **EightTen**: Name of each property follow up your dropdown accordingly.

Comment: I Can't use WeekDays[0] because it is not an array it's IEnumerable. also variable **weekday** is type of WeekDay Class and I can't Iterate through it.

Comment: @Masoud just use `List<Weekday>` then, there is no reason to be using the IEnumerable interface in your case. A `List<T>` allows `T` to be returned by index

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using foreach, use for loop to iterate the weekday list.

```
@for (var weekday=0; weekday < Model.WeekDays.Count; weekday++)
{
<tr>
  <th scope="row">@weekday.DayName</th>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.WeekDays.ElementAt(weekday).EightTen, new SelectList(listItems), Model.WeekDays.ElementAt(weekday).EightTen, new {@class = "custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2"})
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.WeekDays.ElementAt(weekday).TenTwelve, new SelectList(listItems), Model.WeekDays.ElementAt(weekday).TenTwelve, new {@class = "custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2"})
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.WeekDays.ElementAt(weekday).TwelveFourteen, new SelectList(listItems), Model.WeekDays.ElementAt(weekday).TwelveFourteen, new {@class = "custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2"})
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.WeekDays.ElementAt(weekday).FourteenSixteen, new SelectList(listItems), Model.WeekDays.ElementAt(weekday).FourteenSixteen, new {@class = "custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2"})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: thisi is syntactically wrong because weekday is just **int** and it can't represented by an array.